# Aproximation in $W^{1,p}(U)$ with U disconnected.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider $U=(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$. Define $$v(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rc}
0,&\mbox{se}\quad -1<x<0,\\1, &\mbox{se}\quad 0<x<1.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Clearly $v\in W^{1,p}(U)$ for each $1\leq p\leq\infty$. My question is because $v$ can't be approximated (in $W^{1,p}(U)$ norm) by a class function $C^{\infty}(\bar{U}).$

Comment: You only have such an approximation if $U$ has a sufficiently nice boundary. The boundary of $(-1,0) \cup (0,1)$ isn't nice enough.

Comment: You mean $v$ and not $u$, right?

Comment: @levap $u=v$, missprint.